# Remove CRLF end of csv file using Perl

Tags: perl

I have a csv file ending with CRLF in each row record. Using Perl, how to remove the CRLF only in the final record of the file so that there is no empty record row at the end of file?  Thank you.

Comment: I'd say you need to add more detail about your issue. Each line in the csv *should* end with a newline, whether that be CRLF (windows) or just LF (unix). You should not ned to remove this from the last line in the file to prevent an empty record row at the end of the file.

Comment: Consider using one of the existing CSV parsers instead like [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) or [Text::CSV_XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS).  They will likely be faster and less buggy than doing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow the question correctly, there is a line feed trailing the last record, which is creating an empty row at the end of the file.

You can read the file into a scalar and remove the trailing, blank row with a substitution. \R will work on new Perl versions (5.10, I think) and will match any system's line break, otherwise you'll need to use \n or \n\r

```
open $fh, '<', 'test.csv';

while (<$fh>) {
    $str .= $_;
}

$str =~ s/\R+(.*)\R+/$1/s;
```